# StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER, get height of client area

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

According to [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html) I can get the total screen area using `stage.fullStageWidth` & `stage.fullStageHeight`. This total size includes toolbars.

How can I retrieve the client area, only the area where my app will be displayed?

The app was originally developed for iPad and I now want to deploy on Android tablets using mostly the same code. Most android tabs have a client height of around 600px (landscape), and this means that the bottom 168px of my app gets cropped, so all I need to do is detect the height and move some things about at runtime.

Comment: Now that I've posted this question, whenever I do a google search for this the first result is this page. So I must be searching for the wrong keys.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that to know the size of the client area (that is the size of the area where the flash or app is shown) you need to use StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE. When you use NO_SCALE then this size can be read using stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight (and changes detected by listening to Event.RESIZE on the stage).

In any other StageScaleMode, stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight will always return the stage size defined in the stage properties in the app at author time and will never change during runtime.